# Compare row value with column name and highlight the intersecting cell in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, conditional-formatting

I have a dataset like this and i want to highlight  the intersecting cell based on the date1 and date2 value in a row and the corresponding column name
[input dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdpgS.png)

[sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oC6aU.png)

Comment: Is this an Excel spreadsheet?

Comment: No, it's a Pandas dataframe

Comment: Pandas does not have any built-in ability to highlight cells in output like this. The correct method will depend on the program you are using to display the data.

Comment: @shadowtalker - Can we not do it using the conditional formatting? Basically, write a loop to identify the intersecting cell and then apply conditional format. I'm running in Jupyter Nb and need to visualize that way

Comment: [This](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html) style guide may help.

Comment: @NileshIngle indeed, I didn't know about this functionality. My previous comment was wrong and I've posted an answer.

Comment: @NileshIngle i went through it earlier but i'm facing issues with code for finding the intersecting cell based on row val and column name

Comment: @imams if you have a specific problem, you should post your existing code, and state what is different between your current output and your desired output.

Comment: @imams: As suggested by shadowtalker, please provide a reproducible example that has a dataframe, conditions to highlight and a desired output. Because, it is difficult to understand what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

My comment was actually incorrect. Pandas *does* offer conditional formatting / conditional styling for output in Jupyter notebooks. The documentation is here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html

There are actually several ways to implement this, but the simplest way is to check the value of, and set the style for, each individual cell.

```py
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'y': [19, 10, 11, 12]
})

def yellow_highlight_max(series):
    is_max_val = series == series.max()
    return is_max_val.map({True: 'background-color: yellow', False: ''}).tolist()

data.style.apply(yellow_highlight_max)
```

You should carefully consult the documentation for your desired usage.